# Angular Rounting get previous params

Tags: angular, routes

I have the following routes.

I'm navigating to the `test-detail/:id` by the following URL:
`subjects/tests/478/test-detail/170`.

When I'm on the `test-detail/170` page, I have to do http request with `478 ID` which is in this link.

Is there any way to grab `tests/478 ID` from URL?

```js
{
  path: 'subjects',
  resolve: {
    subject: SubjectResolver
  },
  children: [{
      path: '',
      component: SubjectsComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'tests/:id',
      children: [{
          path: '',
          component: TestListComponent
        },
        {
          path: 'test-detail/:id',
          component: TestDetailListComponent,
        },

      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `TestDetailListComponent`, try this:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
....
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.parent.params.pipe(
    // take the params from the parent route and pass the id to function responsible for API call
    switchMap(params => this.service.methodResponsibleForAPICall(params.id)),
  ).subscribe(results => {
    console.log(results);
  });
}
```